# Maven pull dependencies via middle pom file

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

In Maven is it possible to depend on jar1 and jar2 but establish this dependency via a middle pom file like so:

```
mypom.xml --> middle_pom.xml --> jar1, jar2
```

Can this be done in that way?

Of course the packaging for mypom.xml is whatever I want like 'war' but the packaging for middle_pom.xml would be 'pom', agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, make the packaging for middle_pom `pom`, then just add a dependency to mypom.xml like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>middle_pom</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
<dependency>
```

Though if you explain the reason you want to do this someone might be able to give you a more helpful suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, i solved it pretty much after I posted the question and yes I used what you suggested but also in the maven repo for each jar I created a name-version.pom file. Cheers