# Maven dependency grouping via poms

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a multi-module maven project that uses some dependencies from netflix. The trouble is that those dependencies are built using gradle and use a runtime scope. When I build my project I then have only the direct dependency loaded but not it's own dependencies.

To fix that I added dependencyManagement entries to transform all the runtime scopes to compile scopes. They usually go in pack of 10 to 20 entries so what I want is to be able to make some pom that would only address this issue and be able to load it any time I need a dependency.

I know this can be done as i've read [Maven pull dependencies via middle pom file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677987/maven-pull-dependencies-via-middle-pom-file) and [How to use POMs as a dependency in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894032/how-to-use-poms-as-a-dependency-in-maven) but I was wondering how I may carry those poms inside my current multi-module project.

**I'd like to have those in my parent module and avoid needing to create one sub-module per pom. Like pom-dep1.xml, pom-dep2.xml... and have those bundled in my build. Is that possible ?**

Thanks